# How to open Photos by the FileChooser with a certain extension with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, filechooser

I'm making photo manager and I'm searching to know how to get files from the `FileChooser` with some extension:`*.png - *.jpg ...` So which method should I use or which code should I do ?

I tried this: `fileChooser.getExtensionFilters();` but it does not  anything.

Can any body help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [FileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) class has a nested class [ExtensionFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.ExtensionFilter.html). First you have to create an Instance of it:

```
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter imageFilter
    = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.jpg", "*.png");
```

afterwards you can add this Instance to your FileChooser's Extension list:

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
fc.getExtensionFilters().add(imageFilter);
```

A [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code is down below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FileChooserTest extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter imageFilter
        = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.jpg", "*.png");

    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(imageFilter);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Open File");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
      fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("FileChooser Demo");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question helped me so much thank you but can you update your answer and add a condition if the selected file in the filechooser not an image ?

Comment: If the filter is set on a filechooser, than no other files can be selected than png or jpg. If someone changed for example a text file (.txt) to png, than you will run in trouble. But if you want to create a JavaFX Image from that file, this is not relevant, because Image(String url) does not throw an exception on wrong file type.

Comment: sorry i don't understand you. What do you mean "because Image(String url) does not throw an exception on wrong file type." ?

Comment: You are able to place an text file in the constructor url of Image, this only sets the error property of Image but you don't get a thrown exception. So you can read a whole directory with images, even if there is one text file in it, without stopping at an exception.